# Send and Receive files from usb port in c++

Tags: c++, usb

I would like to know the easiest way to send and receive files from a USB port plugin in c++.  I am sorry if this is a question that has been asked but I have done some digging and could not find a straight forward way of doing this.  A library that can do this easily would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would guess the easiest way would be to have a while loop constantly checking your C Drive if a USB port has been inserted into your computer. In order to do that, you have to have the while loop search for a folder named "whatever your usb port is called", and once it found the file, it would copy the files name, make a string that would use the file named saved to create an address to where you would like to store the files you wish (or from where you would like to extract the files you wish). From there you would copy files from one location to another.

Hope that helps :). All of what I said previously should already exist in the  library.